# Becoming an outsider but still being humanoid

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature

Does a player that becomes an outsider as part of a class feature still count as being humanoid for the purposes of things like favored enemy?

Comment: Do they still have two arms, two legs, one head, and roughly bilateral symmetry?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**

Favored Enemy specifically tracks types and subtypes of creatures; becoming an Outsider supplants your normal type, changing the Favored Enemy types you count under. In the flavor, Outsiders are composed of a different essence than other Material beings, making their essence and anatomy subtly different. In RAW, it's a simple type change, with all the things that entails.

For more on Favored Enemy, check the SRD link [here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/ranger.htm), but the important part is here:

> Favored Enemy (Ex)
>   At 1st level, a ranger may select a **type** of creature from among those given on Table: Ranger Favored Enemies. The ranger gains a +2 bonus on Bluff, Listen, Sense Motive, Spot, and Survival checks when using these skills against creatures of this **type**. Likewise, he gets a +2 bonus on weapon damage rolls against such creatures.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Technically, there are some really obscure rules regarding type change that have you gain the "Augmented" subtype with your original type. I.e. Outsider (Augmented Humanoid (Human), Native). I don't know whether or not those rules have a clause saying you count as your original type for things, though.

Comment: As far as I knew, those sorts of subtypes were given on a case-by-case basis depending on the class/template involved.